# is there a difference between searching in txt files and searching in html file in java-android

Tags: java, android, html, search, android-5.0-lollipop

[*]this is a brief explanation of my program:

1- I made a listview of drug names(+8000 name)

2-Every name has  a unique html document in assets folder

3- I made a search bar that search  in the listview

[*]problem: i wanted to imoprove the search function so that it can search inside every html file .
and this is my code :

```
// Filter Class to search in titles and inside html files

public void filter(String charText) throws FileNotFoundException {

    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    druglist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        druglist.addAll(arraylist);

    } else {
        int i=-1;
        for (drugPopulation wp : arraylist) {
            i++;             
            if (wp.getitem().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)||Searchfor(charText, arraylisthtml.get(i).getitem())) {
                druglist.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

*and this is my searchfor function :

```
private boolean Searchfor(String search, String s )  throws FileNotFoundException {
 String   path = "file:///android_asset/"+s;
    Boolean yes=false;

    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if(lineFromFile.contains(search)) {
            // a match!
            yes=true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return yes;
}
```

[*]Results and questions :

1-When i run the app and try this search utility  it doesn't return true results(i think the  searchfor function always returns false ) ,is there a difference between searching in html files and searching in txt files  and what can be the cause of these wrong results ?
2-the search is extremely slow , is there a way to improve it ?
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you only check if the file contains the certain word `String search` in this case, so you don't actually have to read the file line by line, you can just read it as a single string and then call `.contains(search)` on it, this should make the search a lot faster

Also:

```
Searchfor(charText, arraylisthtml.get(i).getitem())
```

Instead of `Searchfor(charText, arraylisthtml.get(i).getitem())` you can just call `Searchfor(charText, wp.getitem())` and get rid of the i.

But most of all, you should probably "preprocess" your data, by that I mean that if you have a way to group and order the files your are going to search trough, do so, and then search them with an optimized algorithm , i.e. alphabetical order - binary search.
You should really try doing that if you want to improve the speed of your search. Good luck! hope I was helpful.

Comment: @Ravzan  thanks a lot for  your answer , how can i read html file as a single string  because i think its not possible to import java.io.IOException;  java.nio.file.Files    ;java.nio.file.Paths;